# Can “draw X” mean the same as “draw on X”

Tags: meaning

In [this silly YouTube animation](https://youtu.be/hrzIykdka4s?t=67), there is a short sequence where a child is drawing a bear, an adult asks her what she is doing and she responds “I’m drawing a bear”. Then the camera zooms out and it turns out she is drawing the bear *on a bear*. The bear then proceeds to eat her. At first I thought this was just meaningless absurdity, but recently I heard [someone](https://tubaro.aperu.net/v/ytb_D8UvB163rjs/#comment-708) claiming that the joke is because “drawing a bear” could also mean the same thing as “drawing on a bear”.

I am a native (British) English speaker and this sounds really odd to me. I could imagine the joke would work if the girl said “I’m painting a bear”, but I can’t imagine that *draw* works in the same way. I can’t find any dictionary references to back up this other meaning of *draw*. What is going on here?

Comment: Painting a (noun) could be understood either way, but I've never encountered 'drawing' used in this way.

Comment: *Draw* can also mean attract.

Comment: YouTube is the cesspool of the internet. Painting a bear works. Drawing a bear doesn't.